# adding extra amount to salary column by using case statements in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

below example is for my learning purpose.Actually am trying add a certain different amounts to salary column in emp table where guys having top salary in each department by using case statement

Using below query i retrieved the top salary in each department

```
select * from (select rank() over (partition by job order by salary desc ) as rank,* from emp) as a where rank=1

a.rank  a.emp_no        a.ename a.job   a.mgr_id        a.date_of_joining       a.salary        a.bonus a.dept_no
1       7788    SCOTT   ANALYST 7566    09-DEC-1982     3000    NULL    20
1       7902    FORD    ANALYST 7566    3-DEC-1981      3000    NULL    20
1       7934    MILLER  CLERK   7782    23-JAN-1982     1300    NULL    10
1       7566    JONES   MANAGER 7839    2-APR-1981      2975    NULL    20
1       7839    KING    PRESIDENT       NULL    17-NOV-1981     5000    NULL    10
1       7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN        7698    20-FEB-1981     1600    300     30
```

## expected Output:

i want to add in different amounts to salary columns based on conditions.

```
a.emp_no        a.job   a.salary
7788    ANALYST 3300
7902    ANALYST 3300
7934    CLERK   1800
7566    MANAGER 3275
7839    PRESIDENT       5200
7499    SALESMAN        2100
```

## Here the below query,correct where am doing wrong in below query

```
select updated_salary,result.emp_no,result.ename,
case when result.salary>1000 and result.salary<=2000 then 'result.salary+500'
    when result.salary>2001 and result.salary<=4000 then 'result.salary+300' when result.salary>=4001  then 'result.salary+200' end as final_result
 from (select * from (select rank() over (partition by job order by  salary desc ) as rank,* from emp) as a where rank=1) as result;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out -

```
--Create table script
create table employee ( emp_no int, job string, salary int);

--Inserting dummy Data 
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7788,"ANALYST",3300);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7902,"ANALYST",3100);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7934,"CLERK",1800);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7930,"CLERK",1500);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7566,"MANAGER",3275);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7839,"PRESIDENT",5200);
insert into employee (emp_no,job,salary) values (7499,"SALESMAN",2100);

--Updated script (issue with passing the salary as string )

select salary,emp_no,job,
case when salary>1000 and salary<=2000 then salary+500 
when salary>2001 and salary<=4000 then salary+300 
when salary>=4001  then salary+200 end as final_result 
from (select * from (select rank() over (partition by job order by  salary desc ) as rank,* from employee) as a where rank=1) as b
;
```

Comment: @rocky...thanks for correcting my mistakes..Now am able to get the result for you case query and mine also